# The tracing segment "spiral". It can cause problems for animation?

Tags: animation, topology

A picture worth more than 1000 words
[image]

Is this bad or can cause problems when animating?

I was trying to replicate this shoulder topology but i commited a mistake in the sequence of the faces of the back and the chest and had this 'spiral trace' thing.

[image]

Comment: I think, no. But it cause problems in modeling - you cant simply select loops with Alt

Comment: Animation Nodes is an addon. So the `animation-nodes` tag should not be used here.

Comment: What kind of problems in modeling can cause?